# Showing that $\int_{0}^\infty \frac{te^{-\varepsilon t}}{t^2 + 1}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. How can I prove that the integral $$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{te^{-\varepsilon t}}{t^2 + 1}$$

exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$0\leq \int_{0}^\infty \frac{te^{-\varepsilon t}}{t^2 + 1}\leq\int_{0}^\infty e^{-\varepsilon t}=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$$

Comment: Very nice, thanks.

Comment: @LutzL $\frac12\le 1$ works here.

Comment: Ok, also true. Using the full power of $0\le (t-1)^2$ would give a stricter, but qualitatively equivalent bound.